# Can we use my own crate repository url in Cargo.toml to download the dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I have my own repository, where I have list of rust crates. When I run the command "cargo run", i want cargo to download all the dependencies from my crate repository url instead of crates.io. To achieve this what configuration need to be done

Looking for some suggestion or code snippet for the same

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/registries.html#using-an-alternate-registry

Comment: I voted to reopen this because the duplicated question is about replacing one specif create from a git repo. The link in the comments above is the answer to this question.